# How to keep Method Parameters Names with Spring Aspect in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I've done what's necessary to get the parameters name in Java 8.
When MyBean has no aspect on it, i get the names: 'first' and 'second'.

But when the aspect is set the bean is marked as MyBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB and all i have is : 'arg0' 'arg1'

This test has been made using spring 4.1.5 and aspectj 1.8.5.

What am i missing ?

```
package com.test;

public class MyBean {

    public void doSomething(String first, int second) {
        System.out.println("something");
    }
}


package com.test;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MinimalAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.test.MyBean.*(..))")
    public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Around before is running!");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("Around after is running!");
    }
}

package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        MyBean myBean = (MyBean) appContext.getBean("myBean");
        for (Method method : myBean.getClass().getMethods()) {
            System.out.print(method.getName() + "(");
            for (Parameter parameter : method.getParameters()) {
                System.out.print(parameter.getType());
                System.out.print(' ');
                System.out.print(parameter.getName());
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println(")");
        }
    }
}


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="myBean" class="com.test.MyBean" />
    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="minimalAspect" class="com.test.MinimalAspect" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is enhancing your bean because of the annotation, so `myBean.getClass()` returns a wrapper class instead of your own class, which has generic parameter names. This should return you the original class

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) appContext.getBean("myBean");
Class clazz = org.springframework.utils.ClassUtils.getUserClass(myBean.getClass());
for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
...
```